# grub 40_custom.save newline error

Tags: grub2

I'm using 16.04 and I have win7 installed. Whenever i try to install something terminal shows me bunch of errors

```
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-39-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-39-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-38-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-38-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-36-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-36-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-122-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-122-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Found Windows 7 (loader) on /dev/sda1
/etc/grub.d/40_custom.save: 2: /etc/grub.d/40_custom.save: Syntax error: newline unexpected
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 2
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.13.0-38-generic.postinst line 1052.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.13.0-38-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-extra-4.13.0-38-generic:
 linux-image-extra-4.13.0-38-generic depends on linux-image-4.13.0-38-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-4.13.0-38-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.13.0-38-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
Errors were encountered while processing:
 friendly-recovery
 linux-image-4.4.0-122-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-122-generic
 linux-image-generic
 linux-generic
 linux-image-4.13.0-39-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.13.0-39-generic
 linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04
 linux-generic-hwe-16.04
 linux-image-4.13.0-38-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.13.0-38-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

and 40_custom.save file looks like this

```
>#!/bin/sh
exec tail -n +3 $0
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
```

there is no new line after second line. 
I also tried deleting these 3 comments but i get same errors.

can anyone help me, this has became rly annoying :(

Comment: It says it is this file 40_custom.save, not 40_custom. Turn off execute bit on  the .save version. `sudo chmod a-x /etc/grub.d/40_custom.save`

Comment: Please don't add "solved" etc. to the question. You can [accept oldfred's answer instead](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have a copy of 40_custom as 40_custom.save.
And grub-update runs any file in /etc/grub.d that starts with two numbers & an underscore and has execute bit turned on.

So turn off the execute bit from 40_custom.save or delete that file.

```
sudo chmod a-x /etc/grub.d/40_custom.save
```